# jQuery Hide Other Dropdowns When Toggled

Tags: jquery

I am using this jQuery snippet to toggle a dropdown menu:

```
  // Dropdown toggle
  jQuery('.ldropdown-toggle').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).next('.ldropdown').toggle();
  });
```

How can I update this so that when one .ldropdown-toggle menu is clicked all other open .ldropdown-toggle menus are hidden.

Comment: jQuery('.ldropdown-toggle').click(function(){
    $(".ldropdown-toggle").not(this).hide();
  });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hide all `ldropdown-toggle` element when you click on one item. And show the clicked item only. The following solution illustrates the above

```js
$('.ldropdown-toggle').on('click', function(){
  $('.ldropdown-toggle ul').not($(this).find('ul')).hide(); 
  $(this).find('ul').toggle();
})
```

```css
.ldropdown-toggle ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left" id="nav">
<ul>
<li class="ldropdown-toggle">
Lighting + Video
  <ul>
   <li>Lighting + Video 1</li>
   <li>Lighting + Video 2</li>
   <li>Lighting + Video 3</li>
   <li>Lighting + Video 4</li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li class="ldropdown-toggle">
Photograms
    <ul>
   <li>Photograms 1</li>
   <li>Photograms 2</li>
   <li>Photograms 3</li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li class="ldropdown-toggle">
About
   <ul>
   <li>About 1</li>
   <li>About 2</li>
   <li>About 3</li>
   <li>About 4</li>
   <li>About 5</li>     
  </ul>
</li></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Almost....however when you click the open item it doesn't close itself.

Comment: @a1anm I have updated the solution. use `toggle()` instead of `show()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.ldropdown-toggle').click(function(){$('.ldropdown').hide();});
```

my the code help you.